# Finding max value of a json field using JsonPath in java

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I went through this document:
https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath

But I couldn't figure out how to find the max value of a specific field.
In the given json, what if I want to find out the price of the most expensive book?

Here is the json:

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
        {
            "category": "reference",
            "author": "Nigel Rees",
            "title": "Sayings of the Century",
            "price": 8.95
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
            "title": "Sword of Honour",
            "price": 12.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "Herman Melville",
            "title": "Moby Dick",
            "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
            "price": 8.99
        },
        {
            "category": "fiction",
            "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
            "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
            "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
            "price": 22.99
        }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 29.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
 }
```

What would be the jsonpath expression (in java) to find the max price for a book. Answer here should be 22.99.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
var myArray = JSON.parse(jsonAsString)["book"];
var max = myArray .reduce(function(a, b) {
   return Math.max(a, b.price);
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume jPathStrB is a StringBuilder of the json above. (Edit: I now realize you are using the other jayway jsonpath library, not the groovy based one. This answer below uses the JsonPath that comes with rest-assured and relies on the groovy "max()" method.)

```
    JsonPath jPath = new JsonPath(jPathStrB.toString());
    jPath.prettyPrint();
    Float price = jPath.get("store.book.price.max()");
    System.out.println("Max price: " + price);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty late to this party, but as of version 2.4.0, JsonPath does not support the behavior you are expecting.

From the maintainer:

> You are trying to apply the function max() to the result of the evaluation. That is not how things work. The function will be applied to each object matching the path.

In order to get your answer, you need to manually add each path to an array:

```
$.max($.store.book[0].price, $.store.book[1].price, $.store.book[2].price, $.store.book[3].price)
```

I think that based on the documentation in the README, most people expect that if the previous works, then this should also:

```
$.max($.store.book[*].price)
```

But instead it throws an error:

```
Aggregation function attempted to calculate value using empty array
```

[Issue #191](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/issues/191%20%22Issue%20#191) has a discussion going back to 2016.
There is also an old pull request: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/pull/197
that appears to have [this enhancement](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/pull/197#issuecomment-264730825) on it, including where to find it on maven central.

Comment: More recently, there was [PR #377](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath/pull/377) was merged that claims to resolve this.